# Is MAP a point estimator? Why?

Tags: machine-learning, map-estimation

In Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book, page 30, section 1.2.6, it says that the MAP estimator for the curve fitting model derived in section 1.2.5 is a point estimator of the model parameters $\textbf{w}$:

[image: Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book, page 30, section 1.2.6]

My question is: why are we calling MAP a point estimator? The posterior distribution can give probabilities for a particular choice of $\textbf{w}$, and it is possible to evaluate the confidence intervals around a particular choice of $\textbf{w}$, say $\textbf{w}_{MAP} \pm \epsilon$.

Comment: What is the definition of the maximum a posteriori estimator?

Comment: If the posterior distribution has a single maximum or mode then this is the MAP and a point which could be used as an estimator.  You can also create a [credible interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) from the posterior distribution (at least if you are working in one dimension) though there is usually no particular reason to expect this to be symmetric about the MAP unless the posterior distribution is symmetric

Comment: @DemetriPananos I am unable to conclude anything from the definition of MAP that answers my question.

Comment: @Henry Does that mean MAP estimators can also be used/termed as interval estimators, i.e. if we are able to compute the confidence/probabilities around the MAP estimate, could that equate to an estimate of the confidence interval around the MAP estimate?

Comment: No - the MAP estimator (the mode of the posterior distribution) is usually a single point.

Comment: A point estimator returns a single estimated value for a parameter. The fact that you can compute a confidence interval for a parameter doesn't mean that an estimator of that parameter is not a point estimator. For Bishop, I think the only point he wants to make is that MAP is not giving you a complete predictive distribution, because this is what he considers the output of proper Bayesian treatment.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum a posteriori estimate is

$$ \theta_{MAP} = \underset{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p}{\arg \min} \ \ \ -\log\big( p(\theta \vert y) \big) $$

Hence, the MAP estimate is the mode of the posterior; the *point* where the posterior achieves largest density.  It is not a distribution, it is an element in $\mathbb{R}^P$, hence it is a point esitmate.

Comment: But is it possible to calculate the confidence of the MAP estimate or can we compute confidence intervals around $\theta_{MAP}$?

Comment: @vicky *Credible* intervals?

Comment: @vicky you have to make assumptions about the shape of the posterior. See “Laplace approximation”. These assumptions are different than MAP.

Comment: @Dave Yes. Credible intervals. Forgive me for using them interchangeably with confidence intervals.

Comment: @DemetriPananos In the curve-fitting example (section 1.2.5), Bishop did not assume any shape for the posterior. It was derived to be the product of the prior and the likelihood. Then he proceeded to find the mode of the posterior. My question is: we can compute the probability distribution around the MAP estimate, so why in section 1.2.6, he says that the MAP estimator is a point estimator?